# Is it possible to bind a value to a file "App Settings" directly into a css stylesheet?

Tags: c#, css, asp-classic, bind

I wanted to know if it is possible to reference the value of my "appSetting" file directly in a style sheet ".css" ? like this:

```
body
{
    background-color: <%$ AppSettings:myColorValue %>;
}
```

This is simply beautiful ^^
Thanks a lot

Comment: C# AND asp-classic? sure you got the right tags there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box, the ASP script ISAPI engine only parses files configured with supported extensions (`.asp`). Also, `.css` files are static and usually cached by the browser.

You could move the `body` style into an `<style>` [tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#edef-STYLE) in your .asp code (e.g. in an `#include`) where it will be parsed the engine.

Comment: Thank's a lot for this explication ^^

Comment: @MehdiBugnard Glad I could remember - its been a while. Out of interest, if your colour is known at compile time, you might also look at frameworks such as [LESS and SASS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LESS_(stylesheet_language)#Comparison_to_Sass)

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. An app settings file is ASP.Net specific, CSS files are not.

You could define your own token scheme however and return a processed, detokenised file that is then cached.

Comment: Thank's a lot for this explication ^^